# How to get accented characters to work in classic ASP generated Excel file?

Tags: sql-server, excel, asp-classic, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I have this classic ASP code that gets data from a SQL Server database, and then creates an Excel file using `Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"`.

However some of the data has names with accented characters. And when I view the data from the generated Excel file, the accented characters get replaced with other characters like `Ã` or `©`, etc...

Is there a way I can get the accented characters to display properly?

Thanks

Comment: try setting the `Response.CodePage` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524628%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I tried `Response.CodePage = 65001` and `Response.CharSet = "utf-8"`, but it worked on the page if I displayed the contents on the page. However for the excel file, the characters are still messed up.